# Why did he bring wine Yitzchok did not ask for?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, grapes-wine, parashat-toldot

In order to give the Brachos Yitzchok requested food from his son:

> וַיָּבֵא לוֹ יַיִן וַיֵּשְׁתְּ

If he asked for food why did Yaakov bring wine?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [Alshich](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43146&st=&pgnum=84), Yaakov was worried that Yitchak might notice that the dish he was served was actually goat meat, which is not an animal that one hunts, as Yitchak had told Eisav to. Therefore, Yaakov served wine with it in the hopes that with the taste of the wine mixed in, Yitzchak wouldn't pick up on the nuances of the taste of the meat he was eating.

Answer (score 5):

Tirgum Yonathan to this pasuk: ".. and he didn't have wine, and a Malach came and gave him wine that was kept from the days of Bereshit Haolam (days of Creation?) and put it into Ya'akov's hand and he gave it to his father...".

A similar commentary we find in Da'at Zekenim Meba'alei Hatosafot. Here we learn that the Malach was Michael. They add that a similar situation was with Avraham and Malkitzedek in which the he brought wine and bread and blessed him.

Comment: I guess this answers the question (and +1 from me) as to why he gave his father wine: I mean, if an angel supplied it for him to do so, then of course he'd do so. It doesn't explain, though, why the angel did so.

Comment: @msh, there is a Midrash somewhere or other that says that the two goats were for the Korban Pesach and Korban Chagigah, as it was Pesach night. If so, then the malach would have given him wine to give to Yitzchak for the Four Cups.

Comment: @Alex, true, and that's a good answer to the original question even without the _midrash_ quoted in this answer.

Comment: Alex you mean this anonymous comment [here](http://parsha.blogspot.com/2009/04/yet-another-birchas-hachama-roundup.html)?